# How do I implement a splash screen Localization based on the phone's language?

Tags: android, cordova

How do I include different languages splash screen in cordova applications or using Android Studio? So for example if an user is opening app in Germany then the app will show the German splash screen image.

Similarly, if the user opens the app in Sweden then the splash screen plugin should select the Swedish image.

So my question is: Can this be achieved in Cordova Ionic application or in Android Studio? And if so, how?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: Actually i am looking for a solution for cordova.

Answer (score 0):

You can put different drawables and layouts in different resource directories such as:

```
res/drawable-en/
res/drawable-it/
```